# Why doesn't django's create_user method validate uniqueness?

Tags: python, django, orm, django-nonrel

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

a = User.objects.create_user("1","2","3")
b = User.objects.create_user("1","2","3")
```

no errors yet...

```
a.validate_unique()
ValidationError: {'username': [u'User with this Username already exists.']}
```

I would expect to receive the validation error when b was being saved as part of `create_user`.

Looking at the [Django Model Instance Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#what-happens-when-you-save), the 'what happens when you save' section does not describe saving at any point.

Is this an intentional design decision or a side-effect due to using django-nonrel?  I would have expected a relational database to return an IntegrityError or something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be using SQLite, which does not support unique key constraints.

`create_user` assumes you've done all the needed checking, usually in a form's validation functions. It gives you quite enough rope to hang yourself with.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using Django-nonrel (with Mongo), but I'd expect Mongo to be good enough to follow  uniqueness constraints.

My solution ended up being creating my own create_user function which did validation before submitting; does that sound reasonable? (I'm not using forms to create his user).

Comment: That's pretty much the normal way of doing things. Database constraints are really a last line of defense, and don't tell you much when they trigger, so it's best to validate input thoroughly before committing to the database.

Answer (score 0):

By default, MongoDB does not block to verify that writes are successful before returning control.

Consider [enabling safe mongo's mode](http://alexeymk.com/2012/08/05/be-safe-with-mongodb.html).